# IIS Active Directory Login, But Run MSXML as Anonymous User

Tags: iis, asp-classic

We currently use the MSXML.dll from Classic ASP for certain parts of our system. On a new site we want the users to be prompted for login using Active Directory.

I have disabled "anonymous access" to the site and I have enabled "Integrated Windows authentication" and "Digest authentication for Windows domain servers". When going to a page that uses MSXML.dll we got permission denied errors because the current user does not have permissions to use that DLL. Rather than give each user permissions to use this DLL, is there a way to run that DLL as the normal IUSR account rather than the logged in user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a group for all the users that will be accessing the site.
2. Add each user into the group.
3. Add the group to the site at the root level and give the group the standard IUSER account permissions, i.e., Read.

The users should be able to access the site just as with anonymous using the IUSER account.

If you're getting the permission denied error, then:

1. Check that there you've provided permissions to other directories that may be connected to the page using the MSXML dll, i.e., a database directory or similar.
2. For the directory that requires execute access for the MSXML dll you'll need to give the group you created above "Modify" permissions for that particular directory, i.e., the database directory.

To verify this, I ran a test on my server and I did see the MSXML access denied permission, but was able to resolve it by giving the group "Modify" permissions as outlined above.

Comment: We ended up going in a different direction, but it does seem this solution would work.